# Pareto Front in R for pre-calculated portfolio return and risk

Tags: r, mathematical-optimization

Suppose you have the following data.frame, `mydata`:

```
dput(mydata)

structure(list(risk = c(3, 4, 7, 3, 8, 10), return = c(50, 60, 
60, 40, 30, 80)), .Names = c("risk", "return"), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Consider that each row in `mydata` represents the risk and return of a portfolio choice. The risk and return are scores, NOT return and variance as in a typical financial portfolio. We wish to maximize the return and minimize the risk of the portfolio by changing the portfolio weights. Let's say I wanted to solve for the optimum portfolio (defined as maximizing return/risk), subject to the constraint that the weights must sum to 1, and no individual weight can be greater than .3. I would solve this as a linear program:

```
library(lpSolveAPI)
my.lp <- make.lp(1+nrow(mydata), nrow(mydata))

#column constraints
set.column(my.lp, 1, c(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1))
set.column(my.lp, 2, c(0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1))
set.column(my.lp, 3, c(0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1))
set.column(my.lp, 4, c(0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1))
set.column(my.lp, 5, c(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1))
set.column(my.lp, 6, c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1))


set.objfn(my.lp,obj=(-1)* (mydata$return/mydata$risk))


#no weight can exceed .3
set.rhs(my.lp, c(rep(.3,nrow(mydata)),1))
set.constr.type(my.lp, c(rep("<=",nrow(mydata)),"="))

solve(my.lp)

print(get.variables(my.lp))
# [1] 0.1 0.0 0.3 0.3 0.0 0.3
```

Now, I would like to solve for optimal allocations for a given risk tolerance, i.e. maximize mean return given the constraint that the mean portfolio risk cannot exceed a set value. I would still like to keep the constraints that the weights must sum to 1, and no individual weight can be greater than .3.  Ideally, I would use this method to generate a pareto front, with the optimal allocation for each level of risk (i.e. max mean return for a level of mean risk).

I'm new to optimization, so if someone could walk me through an approach to this, it would be greatly appreciated.